# Logging to a previous log file without nullifying the file

Tags: java, file, logging

I have a `Logger` that writes to a file like so

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("App");
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("logs/history.log");
log.addHandler(fh);
SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
fh.setFormatter(formatter);
```

The logger unconditionally logs to the file `history.log` all the time. Every time this program is running, it will log to this file. When it is running all works well and it logs perfectly fine. However, when you restart the program, the previous logs in this log file are deleted when the new instance of this program is running. It is not appending to the previous logs that were originally in this file.

I have looked around `Google` and `StackOverflow` to try and find a way to make it so the logs append to the previous logs that were there, but had no luck.

*How would I be able to have the logs in the new instance of the program append to the logs of the past instance? In other words how do I make the logger not delete the contents of `history.log` when a new instance of the program is running.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FileHandler(String, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler-java.lang.String-boolean-) to construct your `FileHandler`, passing `true` for the `append` parameter.

```
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("logs/history.log", true);
```